# Guessing the coin flips

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, probability

Two prisoners, Alice and Bob, are captured by a dragon and placed in separate, isolated cells. The dragon then flips an infinite number of fair coins, and tells the outcomes of odd throws to Alice and of even throws to Bob. He then asks Alice to name an even number and Bob an odd number. If the throws corresponding to the numbers were the same (both heads or both tails), they can both go free. Otherwise the dragon eats them. Alice and Bob cannot hear each other's answers (i.e. they answer simultaneously).

What is a strategy that would allow them to survive with better than 50% probability? They can negotiate the strategy before the dragon flips the coins.

Comment: The question seems unclear, how could one give a finite count of even/odd numbers for infinite attempts? Both counts tend to infinity which is neither an even or odd number.

Comment: Not the _counts_. The _actual outcomes_.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac For example, if instead of infinite flips he only flips the coins 6 times and gets HHTHTH, he would tell Alice HTT (1st, 3rd and 5th throws), and he would tell Bob HHH (2nd, 4th and 6th throws). Alice could then say "2", and Bob could say "3". Because 2nd throw was H and 3rd throw was T, the throws corresponding to the numbers were not the same, and they both lose. If they instead answered "2" and "1", they would both win.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They could ...

> Pair up the odd-numbered and even-numbered flips: 12,34,56,... Now Alice picks the first even number whose corresponding odd number came up heads, and Bob picks the first odd number whose corresponding even number came up heads.

Now

> If 1,2 are H,H then Alice picks 2, Bob picks 1, and they win.
>  If 1,2 are H,T then Alice picks 2, Bob picks *some larger odd number*, and they win with probability 1/2.
>  If 1,2 are T,H then Bob picks 1, Alice picks *some larger even number*, and they win with probability 1/2.
>  If 1,2 are T,T then Alice and Bob ignore those two and continue looking at higher-numbered pairs of coins.

So

> A&B win with probability 1/3 (1 + 1/2 + 1/2) = 2/3.